# What does "tearing your résumé apart in a way" mean?

Tags: expressions, american-english

I asked a résumé checker to check my résumé and she gave me the following answer:

> When you look at the below list of issues, you'll probably think I'm tearing your resume apart. I guess I am, in a way. But, I swear, your resume is pretty good.

What does she mean by *tearing my résumé apart*?

Comment: In context, she's trying to soften the blow that follows; namely the list of edits she suggests.

Answer (score 1):

It is an [idiom](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/idiom) : http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tear+apart

You can usually tell that someone means they are tearing something apart figuratively (not literally), based on the context. For example, you know that the resume checker didn't physically tear your resume apart because she gave you the compliment that "..your resume is pretty good".

It is similar to saying that she "dissected" your resume, which would mean that she cut it apart with a knife and analyzed it methodically. You know she didn't actually do that.

When she says "I guess I am in a way", she means that she is suggesting very extensive edits to your resume which are  semantically/logically equivalent to physically ripping it apart.

Answer (score 0):

Making so many comments that you might think she had torn a physical paper copy into pieces as if it were worthless.

Answer (score 0):

Destroying it metaphorically through excessive analysis.